# Show hide element if scroll bar browser active and no active

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to Show hide div area with `jquery`

if scrollbar or overflow element **active** and **no active**

and this example code for My question

**example html**

```js
$(function(){
    var t = $('#container-ts-plugin-area'),
        s = t.find('.container-ts-plugin-area'),

        e = s.find('.ts-plugin-area'),
        f = (e.outerWidth()+parseInt(e.css('margin-left'),10)+parseInt(e.css('margin-right'),10))*e.length;
    s.css('width', f);
    $('._ts_cont_btn_N_P button').on("click mouseenter", function() {   
        var role = $(this).data('role');
        t.stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: (role=="N")?"+=300px":"-=300px"
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

```css
._ts_cont_btn_N_P {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.plugin-area {
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}

.ts-plugin-area {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:0 5px;
}

._ts_btn_prev_plugin {
  float:left;
}
._ts_btn_N_plugin {
  float:right;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="_cont_plugin_tse">

<div class="_ts_cont_btn_N_P">   <!-- auto show hide -->
    <button class="_ts_btn_P_plugin" data-role="P">&lt;&lt;</button>
    <button class="_ts_btn_N_plugin" data-role="N">&gt;&gt;</button>
</div>

<div id="container-ts-plugin-area" class="plugin-area">
    <div class="container-ts-plugin-area">
    <div class="ts-plugin-area" data-position="1">1</div>
    <div class="ts-plugin-area" data-position="2">2</div>
    <div class="ts-plugin-area" data-position="3">3</div>
    <div class="ts-plugin-area" data-position="4">4</div>
    <div class="ts-plugin-area" data-position="5">5</div>
    <div class="ts-plugin-area" data-position="6">6</div>   
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if element have scrollbar or overflow **active** or **no active** state you need to check if the child element is bigger than the parent element.

Also its depend on your overflow settings of your parent thats its should be `auto` or `scroll` in order to show the scrollbar.

Global example

```js
if($('.child').width() > $('.parent').width()) {
  // then do something
  console.log('scrollbar is active');
}
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  // add something in here
  </div>
</div>
```

And for your code can check if the `.container-ts-plugin-area` width is bigger than the `#container-ts-plugin-area` width and then you show the buttons

And by default to hide this buttons in css

```
._ts_cont_btn_N_P {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

And in the jQuery to add

```
if(s.width() > t.width()) {
    $('._ts_cont_btn_N_P').show();
}
```

here is the full demo of your code
https://jsfiddle.net/p2y79f7x/1/